# Selenium Webdriver : getText() returning empty String for h2 tag

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am having very hard time to get text from **h2** tag. I want **"Product successfully added to your shopping cart"** text.
My Code :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com");
.
.
.
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='layer_cart']/div[1]/div[1]/h2")).getText());
```

This is following HTML Code:

```html
<div class="layer_cart"><span class="cross" title="Close window"/><h2><i class="icon-ok"/>Product successfully added to your shopping cart</h2>
```

Comment: This is HTML Code:Html Code: 
'<div class="layer_cart_product col-xs-12 col-md-6">
'<span class="cross" title="Close window"/>
'<h2>
'<i class="icon-ok"/>
'Product successfully added to your shopping cart
'</h2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the text **Product successfully added to your shopping cart** from `<h2>` tag you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following code block :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='layer_cart']//h2"), "Product successfully added to your shopping cart"));
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='layer_cart']//h2[contains(.,'Product successfully added')]"));
String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', myElement).strip()
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. yes it worked with Webdriver wait condition and i also uses  .getAttribute("innerText") instead of getText()...

Answer (score 0):

This is your HTML structure:

```
<div class="layer_cart">
  <span class="cross" title="Close window"/>
  <h2><i class="icon-ok"/>Product successfully added to your shopping cart</h2>
...
```

You have `h2` as the direct child of `layer_cart`, so you should be able to target it with:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='layer_cart']/h2")).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath : 
**//div[starts-with(@class,'layer_cart')]**

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself why you want to retrieve the text from an element that you already know the exact text of.  I think you may be more interested in checking that the website shows what you're expecting it to at certain points during the test.  I.e. you want to make sure that a h2 with "Product successfully added to your shopping cart" is visible after you add an item to your cart.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Product successfully added to your shopping cart')]")));
```

If the test continues after this point, you know the text was visible when you expected it to be.

Comment: yes visibility was the only issue. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
WebElement y = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='layer_cart']/div/div/h2"));

System.out.println(y.getAttribute("innerText").trim());
```